# Duplicate item showing on JSON generated page

Tags: jquery, arrays, json

I am pulling from a JSON database and showing products on a page. When you click on a product, it shows the product and its appropriate name, upc, imageURL and more in a DIV.

Underneath each specific item, I have a div for similar products. This shows a product that is part of the same category. So if i clicked on tomatoes, it will show the tomato item and a similar tomato product beneath.

The similar products pull from the same JSON database and get randomized and categorized to fit the correct item that was selected. Problem im having is that sometimes it randomizes the same item that is already on the page. How can i prevent a similar product from matching the current item selected on the page?

```
function showSimilarProduct() {
          var categoryItems = [];
          $.each(json, function(i, item){
              if(window.location.hash.indexOf('Tomatoes') >= 0) {
                  if(item.itemCommodity == '1120') categoryItems.push(item);
              }
              if(window.location.hash.indexOf('Olive') >= 0) {
                  if(item.itemCommodity == '2120') categoryItems.push(item);
              }
              if(window.location.hash.indexOf('Torrone') >= 0) {
                  if(item.itemCommodity == 'K410') categoryItems.push(item);
              }
          });

          var similarProduct= '';
          $.each(json, function(i,item){
              similarProduct = categoryItems[Math.floor(Math.random()*categoryItems.length)];
              similarProduct += '<div>' + '<img class="img-responsive img-hover similarProductImagesCategory" src="' + similarProduct.imageURL + '">' + '<h3 class="similarProductSubCategoryImgCaption">' + similarProduct.itemName + '</h3>' + '</div>';
          });
          $('#productSimilar').append(similarProduct);            
      }
```

Comment: It's a bit confusing as to what's in `categoryItems`. You `push` an `item` object, which appears to at least have an `itemCommodity` property on it, and you're writing `item.itemName` to the HTML. Does `itemFound` ever evaluate to anything other than `-1`?

Comment: You are using `similarProduct` for the name of the function, the random item object, and the final appended string.

Comment: im pushing all items in the json array into a temporary one called categoryItems. then i am doing an if statement to narrow down all items in a specific category if the match the item name in window.location.hash. itemFound is just something i was trying to do. i was trying to make it i find a match in the array that equals the product title on the page, hide the duplicate item from displaying